# Javascript returning unexpected date from random string

Tags: javascript

I've got this strange case on javascript date.

My system generates some strange date and after debugging I faced this:

```
new Date('CWE Client-XXX Root 45')
Sun Jan 01 2045 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

Then realised Javascript was getting the last number and returning a date instead of "Invalid Date".

Why this behaviour? Follow some tests bellow. The weird thing is that it doesn't work with all numbers.

```
new Date('1')
Mon Jan 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('2')
Thu Feb 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('3')
Thu Mar 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('4')
Sun Apr 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)

new Date('5')
Tue May 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)

new Date('6')
Fri Jun 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)

new Date('7')
Sun Jul 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)

new Date('8')
Wed Aug 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)

new Date('9')
Sat Sep 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)

new Date('10')
Mon Oct 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)

new Date('11')
Thu Nov 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('12')
Sat Dec 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('13')
Invalid Date

new Date('19')
Invalid Date

new Date('20')
Invalid Date

new Date('29')
Invalid Date

new Date('30')
Invalid Date

new Date('32')
Thu Jan 01 2032 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('33')
Sat Jan 01 2033 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('34')
Sun Jan 01 2034 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('35')
Mon Jan 01 2035 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('36')
Tue Jan 01 2036 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('37')
Thu Jan 01 2037 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('38')
Fri Jan 01 2038 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('39')
Sat Jan 01 2039 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('40')
Sun Jan 01 2040 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('50')
Sun Jan 01 1950 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('80')
Tue Jan 01 1980 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('90')
Mon Jan 01 1990 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

new Date('100')
Fri Jan 01 100 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

Answer (score 1):

The dateString giving in the constructor for a Date object uses [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to convert that into a Date. Here is a quote from MDN on strings that are not in [proper format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime):

> The ECMAScript specification states: If the String does not conform to the standard format the function may fall back to any implementation–specific heuristics or implementation–specific parsing algorithm.

Notice the oddities are from the fallbacks, which can vary by browser. When `Date.parse()` returns `NaN` the Date object will show `Invalid Date` due to the parse failing:

> However, invalid values in date strings not recognized as ISO format as defined by ES5 may or may not result in NaN, depending on the browser and values provided.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `new Date ()` uses `Date.parse(x.toUTCString())` [as specified by EMCA](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.4.2). You can see in section 15.9.4.3 how Date.UTC works.

`Date.UTC (year, month [, date [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, ms ] ] ] ] ] )`

In this case, you are providing just the year.

```
new Date('45')
"Sun Jan 01 2045"
```

When you add a second parameter,

```
new Date('45 12')
"Fri Dec 01 2045"
```

I guess JavaScript is trying to parse the date from your string and since it only recognizes the number, it went with the first option.